# Linked list within linked list: failing to retrieve values

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a linked list of `struct node_delay_info` within each node of another linked list of `struct node`.

I scan lists in two functions: `callback_function()` allocates and fills lists, `study_list()` prints values of `struct node_delay_info`.

While I successfully fill all the fields with `callback_function()`, another scan of the list in `study_list()` doesn't print the values I inserted in the previous function.

Here's the code:

```
typedef struct node_delay_info {
    double delay_info;
    struct node_delay_info *next;
} node_delay_info;

typedef struct node {
    /* bunch of other data */
    ...
    /* useful when reading values from the head list */
    struct node_delay_info *first_elem;
    /* useful when inserting new nodes at bottom list */
    struct node_delay_info *last_elem;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *head = NULL;

/* malloc return values are not checked here for brevity */
void callback_function(/* args */) {
    node *tmp = NULL;
    if (head == NULL) { // if list is empty
        node *new_node = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        node_delay_info *delay_node = (node_delay_info *)malloc(sizeof(node_delay_info));
        new_node->next = NULL;
        delay_node->delay_info = 0.0;
        delay_node->next = NULL;
        new_node->first_elem = delay_node;
        new_node->last_elem = delay_node;
        head = new_node;   
    } else { // if list is not empty
        tmp = head;
        while (tmp->next != NULL) {
            if (/*the node of the list has some matching values for me*/) {
                /* calculating stuff */
                unsigned long delay = ...;
                /* updating the delay_field value */
                node_delay_info *d_info = (node_delay_info *)malloc(sizeof(node_delay_info));
                d_info->delay_info = (double)delay;
                d_info->next = NULL;
                tmp->last_elem->next = d_info;
                /* I checked the value of delay_info field inside d_info struct 
                and it is successfully filled with delay */
                return; // I no longer need to search
            } else {
                /* the node of the list has no matching value, must go forward */
                tmp = tmp->next;
            }
        }
        /* if we are here we are at the end of the list and no element 
        of it matches my values, so I allocate a new node  */        
        node *new_node = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        new_node->next = NULL;
        node_delay_info *delay_node = (node_delay_info *)malloc(sizeof(node_delay_info));
        delay_node->delay_info = 0.0;
        delay_node->next = NULL;
        new_node->first_elem = delay_node;
        new_node->last_elem = delay_node;
        tmp->next = new_node;
    }
}

void study_list() {
    node *temp = head;
    node_delay_info *info_temp2;
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        info_temp2 = temp->first_elem;
        while (info_temp2->next != NULL) {
            printf("%lf -> ", info_temp2->delay_info);
            info_temp2 = info_temp2->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    ...
    /* variables and structs for libpcap */
    pcap_loop(descr, how_many_pkts, my_callback, NULL);
    study_list();
}
```

Output:

> 0.000000 ->
>
> 0.000000 ->
>
> 0.000000 ->
>
> ...

**Edit 1**: running `~$sudo valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ./main` shows the output of `0.000000 ->`  and then reminds me of `x bytes in y blocks are still reachable in loss record`: I guess it refers to the memory allocated with various `malloc` which I didn't free, but I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Did you try to make use of a debugger to step through your code?

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I edited the question with `valgrind` output.
I'll read right now How to Ask and improve my question.

Comment: After setting `tmp->last_elem->next = d_info`, you need to set `tmp->last_elem = dinfo`.

Comment: That seemed to be the problem, @IanAbbott.
Answer to my question and I'll accept your best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code is missing a line to update the tail pointer `tmp->last_elem` after appending a new element to the end of the list.  See the line marked `// <-- This line was missing!` below:

```
        tmp = head;
        while (tmp->next != NULL) {
            if (/*the node of the list has some matching values for me*/) {
                /* calculating stuff */
                unsigned long delay = ...;
                /* updating the delay_field value */
                node_delay_info *d_info = (node_delay_info *)malloc(sizeof(node_delay_info));
                d_info->delay_info = (double)delay;
                d_info->next = NULL;
                tmp->last_elem->next = d_info;
                tmp->last_elem = d_info; // <-- This line was missing!
                /* I checked the value of delay_info field inside d_info struct 
                and it is successfully filled with delay */
                return; // I no longer need to search
            } else {
                /* the node of the list has no matching value, must go forward */
                tmp = tmp->next;
            }
        }
```